# How does Jon's heredity matter?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* season 8 the audience comes to the realization that Jon Snow is no bastard, he's Aegon Targaryen and he's the heir to the Iron Throne. And in the finale we see Jon murder Daenerys probably because of Tyrion's pep talk, especially when he says:

> Do you think I'm the last man she'll execute?

because Daenerys is scared of Jon becoming the King.

One can say that's why he was scared of being killed. But isn't the righteousness of Jon and the fear of Daenerys becoming a tyrant enough to do that? Was the heredity plot necessary at all?

Comment: Even if it didn't I would have been perfectly fine with it, GOT has never been about one person.

Comment: Keep in mind that with Jon being the male heir, Dany has *no claim to the throne whatsoever*. She spent most of the show going on about how it was important that the throne gets the rightful heir, and at almost the last moment, she leans that *she's not it*. But at the same time, she's not going to step down and relinquish her claim. It's one of the many nails in her coffin, and yet another thing showing she *is* just another tyrannical usurper, and that she doesn't really care about the people, only the throne (unlike Jon and Varys).

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, it's necessary.**

You basically answered in your own question:

> Daenerys is scared of Jon becoming the King.

Jon's heredity contributes to Dany's madness, Dany sees Jon is the true heir to the Iron Throne, she sees people love more him than her, she goes mad and burns the entire city.

Comment: **But isn't the righteousness of Jon and the fear of Daenerys becoming a tyrant enough to do that?**

Comment: @Nitwit Do you think she would execute him just because of Jon's righteousness?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel I think the OP clearly _does_ think that. Hence the question.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the show, Jon's claim to the Iron Throne is stronger than Dany's.

- Dany is a female child of  Aerys II, never intended to succeed as ruler.
- Jon is the true son of Rhaegar, the direct male descendant to the throne.

Sexism definitely plays a role in--Targaryan rulers of Westeros are male.  ([Baelor the Blessed](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Baelor_I_Targaryen) married his sisters, but was King where they, as Queens, were subject to him.)

Answer (score 1):

> isn't the righteousness of Jon and the fear of Daenerys becoming a
>   tyrant enough to do that?

Not really. Remember that Jon and Daenerys are/were in love. Jon pulled away from this once he learned the truth of his heritage, because it meant that Daenerys was actually his aunt. This contributed to Daenerys's anger/madness, and gave her a reason to want him killed.

Without the heritage, there would have been no barrier to them being together, there would have been no barrier between her and the throne, and there would have been no reason for her to want to kill him. Perhaps she would not even have done what she did in S08E05.